# Find the solution of $y'=2x+y^2$ with $y(0)=0$

Tags: differential-equations

I am looking for the solution to the equation $y'=2x+y^2$ with an initial condition $y(0)=0$. I know the recurrence relation. Any closed form for the solution?

Answer (score 4):

The solution to $y'(x)=2x+y(x)^2$ for $x>0$, with $y(0)=0$, can be written in terms of Bessel functions,

$$y(x)=\frac{\sqrt{2x} J_{\frac{2}{3}}\left(\frac{2}{3} \sqrt{2} \,x^{3/2}\right)}{J_{-\frac{1}{3}}\left(\frac{2}{3} \sqrt{2} \,x^{3/2}\right)}.$$

Since $J_\nu(x)\propto x^\nu$ for $x\rightarrow 0$ this solution directly shows that $y(x)$ vanishes as $x^2$ for small $x$ (as it should be, because then $y'(x)=2x$).

Answer (score 2):

The Maple command

> [image]

produces the solution

[image]

in terms of Airy functions.

Comment: I've never seen an Airy function with two arguments? $\text{AiryAi}(1,-2^{1/3}t)$ ??

Comment: This is Maple's notation. The one in the first argument means to take a derivative of the Airy function, then evaluate at -2^{1/3)t. Maple can also convert this answer into a form with Bessel functions.